# I can't run python on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Image case for the problem

[image: Screenshot]

I was following the Visual Studio Code tutorial for python here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

I downloaded Python, installed the python extension in Visual Studio Code and set the python interpreter to python3.8 . I also checked the workspace settings to see if it had given the correct path. Then, I wrote a simple hello world program but this is the error it is giving me.

This is the python path it has in the settings.

> C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Program:

`print("Hello World")`

Error:

> C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Users/Dell/hello/hello.py
> -bash: C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe: No such file or directory

I tried uninstalling and installing all the extensions again but it didn't work. I also uninstalled and installed all python related things on my computer. That didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of vs code?

Comment: The first line in the question is the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

reinstall python and this time, add python to the PATH (there is an option on the installation screen. Check it as it isn't checked by default). Then try running vs

Comment: mahen2@DESKTOP-EFSVB24:/mnt/d/Uni/Semester 4/VS Code Practice/Python Practice$ C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe "d:/Uni/Semester 4/VS Code Practice/Python Practice/hello.py"
-bash: C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe: No such file or directory

Comment: I did that and it still gives me this error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your environment path is not configured properly reinstalling python will fix this make sure you install python from actual application and not from vscode.other solution is that you can set the enviornment path manually just go to the environment variables> under user variable set the path to your python.exe the above mentioned location seems unlikely it should contain main python folder such as Python37/....

Comment: looking at your specified location it seems you are missing the main folder, look at this ''C:\Users\kakarotto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\' you are missing the main folder,look for it again and i would suggest not installing python from windows store but go to actual python website and download it from there during installation click the checkbox of path